# Ubuntu Server showing white blank phpMyAdmin

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

My VM Ubuntu Server returning white blank phpMyAdmin

I used this for installing my phpMyAdmin:

````
sudo su
sudo apt install unzip
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.2.0/phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages.zip
unzip phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages.zip
sudo mv phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages /usr/share/phpmyadmin
sudo mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/phpmyadmin
sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp
sudo vim /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf```
````

And added this to `phpmyadmin.conf`:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
<RequireAny>
Require all granted
</RequireAny>
</IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
<RequireAny>
Require all granted
</RequireAny>
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

And did this:

```
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl reload apache2
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us any details like your Ubuntu version, your PHP version, etc. Without details, it is impossible to tell exactly what is wrong with your phpMyAdmin. However, from what you mentioned, your question sound very similar to this: [Not getting the login page after installing the phpMyAdmin](https://askubuntu.com/q/1494804/1157209)

You have to install PHP 8.0 or higher. Since I have no idea which Ubuntu release you are using, I will suggest adding `ppa:ondrej/php` repository, just in case.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install php8.0
sudo a2enmod php8.0
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Also, it is much easier to install phpMyAdmin using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```