# Not getting the login page after installing the phpMyAdmin

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have tried so many times but still, I am getting a blank screen while accessing the phpMyAdmin page. I have checked on google but haven't found the solution.

I have deleted the PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin and reinstalled it again but still getting the same issue. Any idea what is the issue and how can I solved it?

```
:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

**PHP details:**

```
:~$ php -v
PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Sep  2 2023 08:03:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

**phpMyAdmin version:**

```
:~$ dpkg -l phpmyadmin
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version                Architecture Description
+++-==============-======================-============-=================================
ii  phpmyadmin     4:5.1.1+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all          MySQL web administration tool
```

**MySQL Version:**

```
:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

**In `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I am getting:**

```
[Sun Dec 03 17:22:14.931606 2023] [php7:error] [pid 80458] [client 182.48.214.201:39742] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 272
```

Comment: Have you checked apache (webserver) is running and checked the apache logs? Probably `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log` That should tell you if apache or php is giving any errors. By default php won't show errors on the front-end which is likely why you are getting a blank screen - probably a php error of some sort, although you can set `display_errors = On` in `php.ini` file (for development/testing only). Update your original question with any errors you find.

Comment: @codlord, in error.log file i am getting [Sun Dec 03 17:22:14.931606 2023] [php7:error] [pid 80458] [client 182.48.214.201:39742] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjec>

Comment: @codlord, I haven't started any development yet. I am trying to setup the phpmyadmin on Ubuntu server but getting a blank screen while accessing

Comment: A quick web search on that error got me to this phpmyadmin post from 2022 where it looks like it's a version compatibility issue between a library used by phpmyadmin and older versions of php (in your case v7.4). There is some discussion there about patches but would be better to use newer php. I think for your version of ubuntu the packaged version is currently 8.1 so not sure why you have 7.4 https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17503

Answer (score 0):

As [@codlord mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1494804/not-getting-the-login-page-after-installing-the-phpmyadmin#comment2619177_1494804), the error message you are getting is because you are using an older PHP version. To fix the issue, you have to use at least PHP 8.0, or downgrade phpMyAdmin.

#### Why is this happening?

Since version 5.0, phpMyAdmin started using Symfony components, including `DependencyInjection`, where your problem is. Since version 8.0, PHP allows `static` as a return type for class methods.

#### Install and configure PHP 8.1

```
sudo apt install php8.1
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### Downgrade phpMyAdmin

I don't recommend this, but just want to mention it, so you know it's an option. Go to https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ and download some older version of phpMyAdmin. Versions before 5.0 should work with older PHP versions.

Before installing it, make sure you completely purge the problematic version (in your case 5.1.1):

```
sudo apt purge phpmyadmin
```